# How can I show this div content from my function

Tags: php, jquery

```
<button name="saveV" class="btn highbutton" type="button"
                        onclick="if(<?php echo $test?>()) {homepage.test2()}">
```

When I click this button my data is saved in db. All I want to do is to display the contents of a `div` once data is stored. Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call [jQuery's](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) `toggle()` function after saving your data:

```
$("#mydiv").toggle()
```

Comment: i have tried $("#mydiv").show() function but its not working.

Comment: This is an example. `mydiv` is a sample id to be replaced by the id of your div in place. Also you need to add this call at the right position, meaning the moment after your data has been stored. Also, what do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
 
 $("#div1").toggle();
 </script>

Comment: this is what i tried but not working

Comment: Have a look at your webconsole, does it display any errors? Also, have you included jQuery on to your website?

Comment: console is not showing any errors and yes i have included jQuery in my website.

Comment: The way you did your call, `toggle()` will be executed when this script excerpt is loaded - meaning the time your website is loaded. Try this:
`onclick="if(<?php echo $ValidationFunctionName ?>()) {homepage.savethisV();$('#mydiv').toggle()}"` or as a callback after your successfull save.

Comment: not working means its not displaying the contents of the div with id div1.

Comment: Do you want to hide the full div or only the contents, as `toggle()` or `show()` will effect the div itself. Maybe add a little of your code to your question to give a more precise idea

Comment: my div with id div1 only contains a paragraph with a message. so its ok to affect the complete div or its contents because it only contains a paragraph.

Comment: thanks it worked for me.

Comment: onclick="if(<?php echo $ValidationFunctionName ?>()) {homepage.savethisV();$('#mydiv').toggle()}" with this one